# Where does __add__ implicitly implement __iadd__?

Tags: python-3.x, class

Given this simple class definition:

```
class S:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.n = self.n + other.n
        return self
```

and this REPL-session:

```
>>> s10 = S(10)
>>> s20 = S(20)
>>> s10 += s20
```

Brings me to the conclusion that a Python class implementing __add__ implicitly implements the dunder method __iadd__ for assignment expressions as something like this:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    return self.__add__(other)
```

Where can I find the definition in the source code and where in the Python Docs is this mentioned as this behavior is not suggested in [Chapter 3: The Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__).

Comment: _"If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods."_

Comment: The above comment by *CodeCaster* means in other words that *this behavior is suggested in Chapter 3: The Data Model.*